# How to test a page reloading in Rails / Capybara?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I am using Capybara for acceptance testing and I have several scenarios, where I need to test if a page has reloaded or not:

1) If I leave a search input field empty and click on the search icon I want to verify that nothing happens and in particular that the page does not reload.

2) On the results page I have three sorting options for results. When I click on a sorting button the page reloads with the chosen sorting criterion applied. I have some trouble with clicking an element using Capybara or even pure JavaScript, so a means for me to check if the element is clicked at all is to check if the page has been reloaded. So how do I do that?

Comment: I think you're trying to fix the symptom of a much wider issues. I'd concentrate on fixing the issue of clicking elements with Capybara instead. Capybara is made for those actions, the fact that you can't click on an items, is an indication of something you should look into.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, I do need to investigate the Capybara clicking problem. However, this is only one of the two examples, I also have several other scenarios where I want to know if a page has reloaded or not.

Comment: The capybara way is by looking at the items on the page. Are there elements in your page that should or shouldn't be there based on reload? (a table, div, id, etc?) If so, you could check for their existence or lack of.

Comment: That's exactly the thing - the divs I expect not to be there after the click are still there and expected divs are missing. Besides capyabara-screenshots shows a screenshot which hints that no click has happened.

Comment: Does this work as expected when doing it manually? If using cucumber, are you using the @javascript tag?

Comment: Sorry, I am not using cucumber, only capybara/rspec.

Comment: did you tag your examples like so :type => :feature  ? That's the only thing that comes to mind. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: If the divs are not disappearing you may have to chase down your javascript click issue first.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243208/how-can-i-test-in-capybara-that-a-page-has-not-reloaded-javascript-onclick-in/24353804#24353804

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a class to your table (or some other element) based on the sort criterion and test for its existence:

```
page.find_by_css('table.sort_by_foo').should be
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using rspec with that `.should be`. Adjust if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but I'm really interested in testing page reloading than solving this particular example. Nevertheless, thank you once again.

Comment: What I mean is create an initial condition (a default class) and change it when the page is reloaded with a more specific search or sort condition. Create the indicator you need, then test for its existence with Capybara. It will tell you if the page has reloaded. It feels too simple, but sometimes the simple method is best.

Comment: Than I guess I am already doing this because at first the results are wrapped in a div with a particular class, which is supposed to change upon changing the sorting criteria. But that does not solve the case where you just click the refresh button (the same sorting criteria are applied).

Comment: Then include a hidden field with a time stamp. Take the value upon first page load, and test if it changes.

Comment: A random number is another possibility if the time difference is too small.